# (sourcecode wraplines='true') doesn't work with SyntaxHighlighter

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I've recently migrated my wordpress.com blog to wordpress.org.

When my posts include a [**sourcecode**] tag without a **wraplines** attribute, on wordpress.com the lines are wrapped. Meaning that when the lines reach the end of the Right Margin of my Blog, lines are broken and the remaining part is placed on the next line.

On wordpress.org I had to install a plugin called SyntaxHighlighter which is supposed to make the [**sourcecode**] tags work just like on wordpress.com, but when these tags don't include a **wraplines** attribute, they are NOT wrapped. Meaning that, when they reach the end of the Right Margin of my Blog, a Horizontal Scrollbar is created and the line carries on as one long line.

This is exactly what my Tag is:

**[sourcecode language="text" light="true"]**

Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [net/ezswitch/registration/ComponentContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory

**[/sourcecode]**

Here's my Post on wordpress.com:
http://hordine.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/junit-hides-info-with-assertionfailederror-cannot-instantiate-test-case/

And here on wordpress.org:
http://hordine.com/?p=2081

The Code Block is the one at the very bottom of the post.

I'm using wordpress.org 3.4.1 and SyntaxHighlighter 3.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wraplines works only in Version 2 of this Plugin.

To change the Version of the Plugin you have to go to Installed Plugins, and under SyntaxHighlighter Evolved there'll be a Settings link. There you can change the Version to 2.x and also check a Checkbox "Wrap long lines", to make it wrap the lines by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and my solution was to fit the size of the font:

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. I don't want to have to change my font-size every time I have a new sourcecode that doesn't fit in its box.